# How can I troubleshoot/resolve Wordpress on AWS not responding?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I recently follow these two sets of instructions to set up a Wordpress installation on an EC2 instance:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html

I followed the tutorials and was able to successfully get Wordpress up and running with know problems. I went through the install and then used scp to put my them in and used the WP interface to activate it (even installed the sample content that came with the theme I bought).

However, after a few hours, when I navigated to my elastic IP in my browser, my browser just hangs and reports "Waiting for MY.IP.AD.DR"

When I tried to SSH I got:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

When I ping'ed I got: `Request timeout...`

The strange thing is that after this happened, I just walked away for the night and when I checked the next afternoon (11am or so), my site was live again but around 4-6pm today, it became unresponsive again.

I'm not sure where to start trouble shooting this but if it becomes active again, I was going to check my apache config and logs. Does anyone have any suggestions to try? Or, does anyone have any troubleshooting tips I should try if/when the site become responsive again? My EC2 instance doesn't show any problems in the AWS console.

**UPDATE:**
Per BMW's suggestion, I check out the security group and here is the settings I have which I believe are correct:

Inbound:

SSH
TCP
22
0.0.0.0/0
HTTP
TCP
80
0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS
TCP
443
0.0.0.0/0

Outbound

All traffic
All
All
0.0.0.0/0

I also checked the logs and noticed this:

```
[125535.879140] Out of memory: Kill process 3670 (httpd) score 88 or sacrifice child
[125535.882988] Killed process 3670 (httpd) total-vm:461340kB, anon-rss:88776kB, file-rss:316kB
[128726.764226] sshd invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=-1000
[128726.767628] sshd cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
[128726.769340] CPU: 0 PID: 2104 Comm: sshd Not tainted 3.14.27-25.47.amzn1.x86_64 #1
[128726.772756] Hardware name: Xen HVM domU, BIOS 4.2.amazon 12/03/2014
[128726.775326]  0000000000000000 ffff88003bab9988 ffffffff8148586b ffff880037a332a0
[128726.778595]  ffff88003bab9a10 ffffffff81482a32 ffff88003ffdab00 ffff88003bab9b00
[128726.782192]  ffffffff8114c705 ffffffff8108e40d 0000000000000046 ffff88003db1b2a0
```

Could there be something misconfigured with httpd?

Comment: Check "security group" if set properly. Seems you didn't open the firewall and  port to your client IP.

Comment: Thanks BMW, I will check this. I'm concerned it's not a security group issue because it was at one time working, accepting requests on port 22 and 80